# How to iterate through characters in a string in Rust to match words?

Tags: string, iteration, rust

I'd like to iterate through a sentence to extract out simple words from the string. Here's what I have so far, trying to make the `parse` function first match `world` in the input string:

```
fn parse(input: String) -> String {
    let mut val = String::new();

    for c in input.chars() {
        if c == "w".to_string() {
            // guessing I have to test one character at a time
            val.push_str(c.to_str());
        }
    }

    return val;
}

fn main() {
    let s = "Hello world!".to_string();
    println!("{}", parse(s)); // should say "world"
}
```

What is the correct way to iterate through the characters in a string to match patterns in Rust (such as for a basic parser)?

Comment: Note that your example doesn't compile on the latest Rust from tip. Use `c == 'w'` to compare characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking for words in a string is easy with the [`str::contains`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.contains) method.

As for writing a parser itself, I don't think it's any different in Rust than other languages. You have to create some sort of state machine.

For examples, you could check out [`serialize::json`](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rustc-serialize). I also wrote a [CSV parser](https://github.com/BurntSushi/rust-csv/) that uses a buffer with a convenient `read_char` method. The advantage of using this approach is that you don't need to load the whole input into memory at once.

Comment: I cleaned up your answer to remove some out-of-date aspects, but wasn't sure about the current architecture of rust-csv, so you might want to edit further...